# Logging of database SQL query execution time directly with EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ssms

I am currently working on a project that measures the execution time(Server-Side) of SQL statements and visualizes the result to compare it with other database. I am using EF Core 6 and SQL Server.

The problem is that the EF Core logs execution times does not match the times in any way, from SSMS and I wonder why?
(factor > 10x)

I measured the execution time twice (to have a second value)

1. Once with EF Core logger (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command -> Executing DbCommand`) [MS EF Core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/performance-diagnosis?tabs=simple-logging%2Cload-entities)
2. And with SSMS (before/after the SQL statement with `set statistics time on/off`)

Example for one SQL statement:

- EF Core: 49-60 ms
- SSMS: 377-1551 ms

Comment: Network latency? GUI overhead for SSMS to create and populate a massive grid control to display the results? Different `@@OPTIONS` values causing different execution plans to be compiled and executed?

Comment: `measured the execution time twice` this guarantees invalid values. Databases cache data aggressively which means the second query will be faster than the first simply because the data is already loaded in memory. That's why raw execution time is rarely used to optimize performance. On top of that, your results depend on the actual code. `Find` actually caches the objects it loads so calling `Find` twice in the same context will return the already loaded object

Comment: Without the actual benchmark code one can only guess. Measuring wall clock time is definitely wrong and *my* guess would be that the EF Core code returns already cached objects. Never mind different configuration options in SSMS. At the very least use ADO.NET directly instead of SSMS to get direct execution times. You'll still have to clear SQL Server's data and execution plan buffers between test iterations. To get meaningful results use BenchmarkDotNet to repeat each test enough times to generate statistically meaningful results

Comment: Check [SQL Server commands to clear caches before running a performance comparison](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10818/sql-server-commands-to-clear-caches-before-running-a-performance-comparison). At the very least execute `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` before each test

Comment: Are you saying you generated the SQL and ran it in SSMS? Because there are many reasons (foremost parameter sniffing) that this will give a different result. May I suggest the best solution for analysing query performance is actually the sql server query store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply running the same query twice guarantees invalid values. Databases cache data aggressively which means the second query will be faster than the first simply because the data is already loaded in memory. That's why raw execution time is rarely used to optimize performance.

On top of that, results depend on the actual code. [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.find?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) actually caches the objects it loads so calling [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.find?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) twice in the same context will return the already loaded object. If the code uses a singleton/shared DbContext, it's always using cached data. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection.

Without the actual code one can only guess what's going on. The *correct* way to measure database performance is to first ensure any database buffers are cleared and *then* execute each test enough times to get statistically meaningful results. The common way to measure performance is to use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/index.html) to repeat each test enough times to ensure valid results.

Instead of using SSMS to measure "direct" performance, one should use ADO.NET directly. This allows running the test through code and eliminates differences due to application settings.

One possible benchmark could look like this:

```
public class EFvsDirect
{
    string _connectionString;
    DbContextOptions<TestContext> _options;

    public class EFvsDirect()
    {
        _connectionString=".....";
        _options=new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(_connectionString).Options;
    }

    [IterationSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var sql="DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS";

        using con=new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        using var cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,con);
        con.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void DirectQuery()
    {
        var sql="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ID=5";

        using con=new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        using var cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,con);

        //Execute the query
        using var reader=con.ExecureReader();
        //Load results
        var table=new DataTable();
        table.Load(reader);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void EfQuery()
    {
        using ctx=new TestContext(_options);
        var product=ctx.Products.Find(5);
    }
}
```